# Wordpress maintenance mode function

Tags: wordpress

I want to enable the maintenance mode in wordpress when the condition is met.  I wanted to enable this mode permanently for everyone and check the condition by cron 2 times a day. Only I could turn it off manually. I tried different solutions but they do not want to work. The code I have for this moment

```
function do_this_hourly() {

if(2>1){

    // Activate WordPress Maintenance Mode
function wp_maintenance_mode() {
    if (!current_user_can('edit_themes') || !is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_die('<h1>Under Maintenance</h1><br />Something aint right, but were working on it! Check back later.');
    }
}
add_action('get_header', 'wp_maintenance_mode');
} else {
    echo "page work";
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error?

Comment: did you call this function `do_this_hourly`?

Comment: yes a call by cron for test every 2 minutes

Comment: cron will runs background. you need to call this function in `get_header` or `wp_header`

Comment: I know about it, I wanted to enable this mode permanently after fulfilling the condition